# How do I iterate through all items in GridView?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

*This might be the simplest but I am C# beginner so bear with me.*

I have a GridView (in XAML), with some data bound. How can I iterate through each item when app loads? I am building Win 8.1 app using XAML/C#.

My GridView:

```
    <GridView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MeetingTileSelector}"
        x:Name="itemGridView">
    </GridView>
```

I wanted to read what each items contains (like image or video, or just a line of texts) and then apply ColSpan, RowSpan, Height accordingly. All I don't know how to iterate through the items.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in itemGridView.Items)
{
//do stuff with (each) item
}
```

given that your grid view is binded to its data source at the moment when you wish to do this iteration.

Check [this msdn class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) for more info on the GridView.

If you are looking to change the style of your grid view items, use the

```
itemGridView.ItemContainerStyle
```

property of the grid view

Comment: @BartoszKP this is not clear to me, because of http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx

Comment: This does the iteration properly. But `item` is returned as the data item object. I need Item of that Gridview so that I can assign ForeGround, RowSpan and ColSpan. How can I do that?

Comment: @shekhardesigner Oh, you want to modify the style of an item. I don't think its possible to modify individual items' styles. But, it should be possible to change the item style at grid view level.

Comment: @shekhardesigner try playing with the ItemContainerStyle property of the GridView. But again, this will change the style of all your items.

Answer (score 2):

just try these code, it should work.

```
        foreach (var item in groupedItemsViewSource)
        {
           var gridViewItem = (FrameworkElement)itemGridView.ContainerFromItem(item);
        }
```

Best regards!

**[EDIT]**
***IMPORTANT***: the above code will not work. I just have not realized that **groupedItemsViewSource** is a **CollectionViewSource**.

From your code, I guess **groupedItemsViewSource** is most likely be defined like this:

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="groupedItemsViewSource"
                          IsSourceGrouped="True"
                          Source="{Binding SomeProperty, Source={StaticResource SomeObject}}"
                          ItemsPath="Items" />
```

If so, then your can not cast **groupedItemsViewSource** as **CollectionViewSource** for iretating purpose.Instead, just iretate Items directly:

```
        foreach (var item in SomeObject.SomeProperty.Items)
        {
           var gridViewItem = (FrameworkElement)itemGridView.ContainerFromItem(item);

          //here you can do something about the gridViewItem(such like iretating its children)
        }
```

Comment: And what should be `groupedItemsViewSource`? The GridView or ??

Comment: @SimonFisher you are iterating through the data source. What if changes are made in the GridView between binding and the iteration time?

Comment: Can't iterate on that given by @SimonFisher, it says there is no public Enumerator!

Comment: @shekhardesigner I believe groupedItemsViewSource is the data source of the grid view. This would be faulty if modifications are done to the grid view and do not reflect in the data source.

Comment: @shekhardesigner Did you try iterating through the Items property of the grid view, as I stated in my answer?

Comment: groupedItemsViewSource is StaticResource. If it is defined in the Resource of this page, then you can get it in the code behind like this: var list = this.Resource["groupedItemsViewSource"] as ("the type of your groupedItemsViewSource");

Comment: @nestedloop, I don't get it, but,afaik, that's the easiest way to iretate the items of GridView/ListView/ListBox...

Comment: @SimonFisher: it still says same :(